# Retrieving the plan Id from the subscription object

Tags: stripe-payments, payment-gateway

I have a subscription object in stripe that I created by means of the checkout session . Here's what I specified when I created the session :

```
            'mode' => 'subscription',
            'line_items' => [[
                'price' => $planId,
                'quantity' => 1,
            ]],
```

My question is do I always have the following statemet true in my case because of quantity = 1?

`$subscription_obj->items->data['0']->plan->id== $subscription_obj->plan->id`

Because I my code whenever I needed the plan Id I sometimes used the left hand side expression and sometime sthe right hand side.  so I just wanna make sure that these are identical in my case and there won't be any :
`$subscription_obj->items->data['1']->plan->id` ...

```
Here's my subscription object for a plan of 12 euros/month:
```

````
[id] => sub_J75FZOObndggWX
    [object] => subscription
    [application_fee_percent] => 
    [billing_cycle_anchor] => 1615717329
    [billing_thresholds] => 
    [cancel_at] => 1620984129
    [cancel_at_period_end] => 
    [canceled_at] => 1615717335
    [collection_method] => charge_automatically
    [created] => 1615717329
    [current_period_end] => 1618395729
    [current_period_start] => 1615717329
    [customer] => cus_J75Fs7RnQtMBTX
    [days_until_due] => 
    [default_payment_method] => pm_1IUr5IHEWYmoXN4GjeSdn3aK
    [default_source] => 
    [default_tax_rates] => Array
        (
        )

    [discount] => 
    [ended_at] => 
    [items] => Stripe\Collection Object
        (
            [object] => list
            [data] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Stripe\SubscriptionItem Object
                        (
                            [id] => si_J75F5QEL5Gnzqf
                            [object] => subscription_item
                            [billing_thresholds] => 
                            [created] => 1615717329
                            [metadata] => Stripe\StripeObject Object
                                (
                                )

                            [plan] => Stripe\Plan Object
                                (
                                    [id] => price_1IJes9HEWYmoXN4GiFeNywqa
                                    [object] => plan
                                    [active] => 1
                                    [aggregate_usage] => 
                                    [amount] => 1200
                                    [amount_decimal] => 1200
                                    [billing_scheme] => per_unit
                                    [created] => 1613048777
                                    [currency] => eur
                                    [interval] => month
                                    [interval_count] => 1
                                    [livemode] => 
                                    [metadata] => Stripe\StripeObject Object
                                        (
                                        )

                                    [nickname] => 
                                    [product] => prod_IvVt5EemrpxKcf
                                    [tiers_mode] => 
                                    [transform_usage] => 
                                    [trial_period_days] => 
                                    [usage_type] => licensed
                                )

                            [price] => Stripe\Price Object
                                (
                                    [id] => price_1IJes9HEWYmoXN4GiFeNywqa
                                    [object] => price
                                    [active] => 1
                                    [billing_scheme] => per_unit
                                    [created] => 1613048777
                                    [currency] => eur
                                    [livemode] => 
                                    [lookup_key] => 
                                    [metadata] => Stripe\StripeObject Object
                                        (
                                        )

                                    [nickname] => 
                                    [product] => prod_IvVt5EemrpxKcf
                                    [recurring] => Stripe\StripeObject Object
                                        (
                                            [aggregate_usage] => 
                                            [interval] => month
                                            [interval_count] => 1
                                            [trial_period_days] => 
                                            [usage_type] => licensed
                                        )

                                    [tiers_mode] => 
                                    [transform_quantity] => 
                                    [type] => recurring
                                    [unit_amount] => 1200
                                    [unit_amount_decimal] => 1200
                                )

                            [quantity] => 1
                            [subscription] => sub_J75FZOObndggWX
                            [tax_rates] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                )

            [has_more] => 
            [total_count] => 1
            [url] => /v1/subscription_items?subscription=sub_J75FZOObndggWX
        )

    [latest_invoice] => in_1IUr5JHEWYmoXN4GTmJ3pJUZ
    [livemode] => 
    [metadata] => Stripe\StripeObject Object
        (
            [myID] => 1
        )

    [next_pending_invoice_item_invoice] => 
    [pause_collection] => 
    [pending_invoice_item_interval] => 
    [pending_setup_intent] => 
    [pending_update] => 
    [plan] => Stripe\Plan Object
        (
            [id] => price_1IJes9HEWYmoXN4GiFeNywqa
            [object] => plan
            [active] => 1
            [aggregate_usage] => 
            [amount] => 1200
            [amount_decimal] => 1200
            [billing_scheme] => per_unit
            [created] => 1613048777
            [currency] => eur
            [interval] => month
            [interval_count] => 1
            [livemode] => 
            [metadata] => Stripe\StripeObject Object
                (
                )

            [nickname] => 
            [product] => prod_IvVt5EemrpxKcf
            [tiers_mode] => 
            [transform_usage] => 
            [trial_period_days] => 
            [usage_type] => licensed
        )

    [quantity] => 1
    [schedule] => 
    [start_date] => 1615717329
    [status] => active
    [transfer_data] => 
    [trial_end] => 
    [trial_start] => 
)
```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you're right. You can also add a guard clause to check that the size of `data` is 1, if that is what you always expect it to be. `quantity` doesn't help in your case, it refers to the number of that particular `Plan` that your `Customer` is subscribed to, it doesn't imply the size of `data`.

Comment: Thanks !! Just another unrelated question  : In which case  do we see :
```$subscription_obj->items->data['1']->plan->id``` and ['2'] and so on .. ?

Comment: Is this generated if we add many line items ? and In my case it's just 0 because I have only one line item ?

Comment: No problem. If my answer helped, please accept my answer. As for your question, only if you create more than 1 subscription item https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/create#create_subscription-items

Comment: `so my code would be like this to have data[1].. true?

 'mode' => 'subscription', 'line_items' => [[ 'price' => $planId1,'quantity' => 1,]`[ 'price' `=> $planId2, 'quantity' => 1,]],`

Comment: Yes. You should also try it out in test mode to have a look. We all learn better by doing it. :)